# Flexbox children don't always expand as wide as they could/should

Tags: css, flexbox

Two of the link buttons in my `nav` have long-ish names, and they're text-wrapping and becoming two lines tall even though (as far as I can tell) there's nothing stopping them or the `nav` from growing wider. Have I just missed something?

The code is quite long, so you'll probably be happier viewing the [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VeMzvm) than reading it here. It's so long because I'm afraid something I've overlooked in my global styling or my media query changes is to blame for this bug.

**EDIT:** This one was an easy answer. I misunderstood selector precedence. I thought media queries took precedence over everything (except inline). So I didn't realize the `nav a` rule in my media query was not overwriting the `nav > section > a` in my base CSS. A good lesson about always respecting CSS selector precedence.

**HTML**

```
<section>
    <nav>
        <a id="NSFW_deactivateFilter" onClick="worksafeOff()" href="#">Worksafe Mode: On</a>
        <h2 onClick="showMenu()">Category Filters</h2>
        <div></div>
        <section id="nav_Orientation">
              <a id="Horizontals" href="#">Horizontals</a>
              <a id="Verticals" href="#">Verticals</a>
        </section>
        <div></div>
        <section id="nav_Category">
              <a id="Biltmore" href="#">Biltmore</a>
              <a id="Commercial" href="#">Commercial / Product</a>
              <a id="Fashion" href="#">Fashion &amp; Glamour</a>
              <a id="Invocation" href="#">Invocation</a>
              <a id="NewOrleans" href="#">New Orleans</a>
        </section>
    </nav>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
/** GLOBAL **/
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    color: inherit;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-style: inherit;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    z-index: 1;
}
a {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
body {
    background-color: #444;
    color: #ccc;
    font-family: Cambria, "Hoefler Text", "Liberation Serif", Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
    font-style: normal;
}
body > section {
    background-color: #333;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1440px;
}

/** NAV **/
nav {
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #222;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 95%;
    max-width: 480px;
}
nav a, nav > h2 {
    border: 1px solid #666;
    margin: 0 0 5px 0;
    padding: 5px;
}
nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
nav > a, nav > h2 {
    width: 100%;
}
nav > a {
    background-color: #666;
}
nav > div {
    display: none;
}
nav > section { 
    align-items: center;
    display: none;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin: 0;
    width: 95%;
}
nav > section.nav {
    display: flex;
}
nav > section > a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 48%;
}


/** MEDIA QUERIES **/
@media (min-width: 1000px) {
    nav {
        display: inline-flex;
        flex-flow: row nowrap;
        width: auto;
        max-width: none;
    }
    nav a {
        margin: 0 5px;
        width: auto;
    }
    nav > h2 {
        display: none;
    }
    nav > div {
        background-color: #666;
        display: block;
        height: 20px;
        margin: 0 5px;
        width:1px;
    }
    nav > section { 
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: row nowrap;
        width: auto;
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like they are wrapping because you're setting `width: 48%` on the anchor elements (with the selector `nav > section > a`)... Updated example -> http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jWGLVX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `width: 48%;` rule from `nav > section > a`.

See [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XXeapW).

Comment: I already have the media query applying `width: auto` to every `a` element, which I thought was supposed to cancel that `width: 48%` out (I can't just remove it; I need it for the mobile layout).

Comment: @JosephLeeSaxon Selector `nav > section > a` is more specific than just `a`, so it's rules overwrites `a`'s rules.

Comment: @JosephLeeSaxon Why do you need it for mobile layout? What it is supposed to do?

Comment: Okay, I misunderstood selector precedence (I thought media queries took precedence over everything except inline). That fixes it, thank you.

I need the width rule so that I'll get two menu buttons per line. If you shrink your codepen down below 1000px you'll see they get too small without it (and also distribute in a totally bizarre way; flexbox `wrap` calculations seem quirky as heck to me).

Comment: @JosephLeeSaxon Maybe try `min-width` instead of `width`.